# How to trigger a Webhook job initiated by HTTP request on Chainlink?

Tags: chainlink

I was trying to create a job on Chainlink node operator that would be triggered by HTTP request, but I couldn't find anything helpful. Has anyone create this type of job? Only information about trigger a job with an HTTP request is here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/types/webhook/
But I couldn't find an example of how to do it

Comment: It looks like the docs come with an example though?